# Test that a scala singleton object's method is calling another method

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking

I have a scala singleton object that I want to test that looks basically like this

```
object myObj {

  def m1(a1: String):String = {

    if(a1 == "somthing") {
      m2
    } else {
      m3
    }

  }

  def m2():String = {

    "do somthing"

  }

  def m3():String = {

    "do somthing else"

  }

}
```

All I want to test is that m2 is called by m1 when its supposed to.

I don't have allot of experience with mocking.  I've been looking at the zillions of posts on mocking and they all seem overly complicated for what I need to do.  I'm open to using any libraries that will do the trick simply.

Note: I really want to use a singleton object here and in my real logic I can't just test the return value of m1

Comment: Is there some reason that just checking the return value of m1 isn't sufficient for your test?

Comment: yes there is a reason.  without getting to far into it,  i am unable to do that in my test environment.  So I'd like to just test that m2 gets called by mocking it somehow.

Comment: Is m2 producing some sort of side effect, like accessing a database or something? If so, then your best best would be to mock the environment the side effect takes place in.